# List comprehension with duplicated function call

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I want to transform a string such as following:

```
'   1   ,   2  ,    ,   ,   3   '
```

into a list of non-empty elements:

```
['1', '2', '3']
```

My solution is this list comprehension:

```
print [el.strip() for el in mystring.split(",") if el.strip()]
```

Just wonder, is there a nice, pythonic way to write this comprehension without calling `el.strip()` twice?

Comment: Where did the string come from? How was it created?

Comment: Duplicate of [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26672532/2301450) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40539357/2301450) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41112035/2301450) [4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15812779/2301450). Just enter the title of this question into Google search.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use a generator inside the list comprehension:

```
  [x for x in (el.strip() for el in mylist.split(",")) if x]
#             \__________________ ___________________/
#                                v
#                        internal generator
```

The generator thus will provide stripped elements, and we iterate over the generator, and only check the *truthiness*. We thus save on `el.strip()` calls.

You can also use [`map(..)`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#map) for this (making it more functional):

```
  [x for x in map(str.strip, mylist.split(",")) if x]
#             \______________ ________________/
#                            v
#                           map
```

But this is basically the same (although the logic of the generator is - in my opinion - better encapsulated).

Answer (score 8):

As a simple alternative to get *a list of non-empty elements* (in addition to previous good answers):

```
import re

s = '   1   ,   2  ,    ,   ,   3   '
print(re.findall(r'[^\s,]+', s))
```

The output:

```
['1', '2', '3']
```

Answer (score 5):

How about some `regex` to extract all the numbers from the string

```
import re

a = '   1   ,   2  ,    ,   ,   3   '
print(re.findall(r'\d+', a))
```

Output:

```
['1', '2', '3']
```

Answer (score 3):

In just one line of code that's about as terse you're going to get. Ofcourse, if you want to get fanciful you can try the functional approach:

```
filter(lambda x: x, map(lambda x: x.strip(), mylist.split(',')))
```

But this gets you terseness in exchange for visibility

Comment: the `map` i find a bit over the top. You can just put OP's comprehension in there without the `if`

Comment: i figured i'd go functional all the way and not 'spoil' it :)

Comment: `filter(None,map(str.strip, mystring.split(",")))` would be a lot less ugly if you insist on the functional apporach

Comment: didn't know about the None part.... but the str.strip should have been obvious. thanks :)

Comment: I like this solution. However, I decided to accept Willem's answer, would like to stick with generators...

Comment: his solution is more readable too... but AFAIK both map and filter use generators underneath

Comment: @omu_negru: In Python-3.x, these are indeed generators. In Python-2.x `filter` and `map` produce lists, and this can unfortunately result in memory problems, since in that case more items are put into memory.

Answer (score 2):

Go full functional with `map` and `filter` by using:

```
s = '   1   ,   2  ,    ,   ,   3   '
res = filter(None, map(str.strip, s.split(',')))
```

though similar to @omu_negru's answer, this avoids using `lambda`s which are arguably pretty ugly but, also, slow things down.

The argument `None` to filter translates to: filter on truthness, essentially `x for x in iterable if x`, while the `map` just maps the method `str.strip` (which has a default split value of whitespace) to the iterable obtained from `s.split(',')`.

On Python 2, where `filter` still returns a list, this approach should easily edge out the other approaches in speed.

---

In Python 3 one would have to use:

```
res = [*filter(None, map(str.strip, s.split(',')))]
```

in order to get the list back.

Answer (score -1):

If you have imported "re", then re.split() will work:

```
import re
s='   1   ,   2  ,    ,   ,   3   '
print ([el for el in re.split(r"[, ]+",s) if el])
['1', '2', '3']
```

If strings separated by only spaces (with no intervening comma) should not be separated, then this will work:

```
import re
s=' ,,,,,     ,,,,  1   ,   2  ,    ,   ,   3,,,,,4   5, 6   '
print ([el for el in re.split(r"\s*,\s*",s.strip()) if el])
['1', '2', '3', '4   5', '6']
```

Comment: But this will also remove the space in between an element. For instance `' a b, qux foo, 1 2 3'`. Will result in `'a', 'b', 'qux', 'foo', '1', '2', '3'`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem , It is not clear, but OP wants only numbers, not alphanumeric strings. Check the answer by RomanPerekhrest which uses regex r'[^\s,]+' (6 upvotes with no negative comments, but it implicitly has the same problem you mention) ; Check the answer by Miraj50 which says "extract all the numbers from the string" (3 upvotes with no negative comments, but it explicitly has the same problem you mention) ; I know what you are saying and I have specifically included "4   5" in my answer. I wonder why my answer is so bad or wrong to get only downvotes ....

Comment: I did not downvote. I agree the same comment applies to RomanPerekhrest. Nevertheless usually one favors generic robust and flexible methods over methods that can only fix the exact problem: if later the OP changes his mind a bit, then this solution might stop working.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem , thanks for the feedback. I have added a minor edit to my answer. I have upvoted your correct answer. [[ If OP later changes his mind a bit, then he will also have to change the code a bit, whether he uses your snippet or mine or something else ]]

Answer (score -1):

List comprehensions are wonderful, but it's not illegal to use more than one line of code! You could even - heaven forbid - use a for loop!

```
result = []
for el in mystring.split(",")
    x = el.strip()
    if x:
        result.append(x)
```

Here's a two-line version. It's actually the same as the accepted answer by Willem Van Onsem, but with a name given to a subexpression (and a generator changed to a list but it makes essentially no difference for a problem this small). In my view, this makes it a lot easier to read, despite taking fractionally more code.

```
all_terms = [el.strip() for el in mystring.split(",")]
non_empty_terms = [x for x in all_terms if x]
```

Some of the other answers are certainly shorter, but I'm not convinced any of them are simpler/easier to understand. Actually, I think the best answer is just the one in your question, because the repetition in this case is quite minor.

Comment: I'd appreciate feedback on the downvotes. Was it the sarcasm (admittedly unnecessary) or are voters really that against splitting code into multiple statements for clarity?